# Show that all the roots of $\frac{dx}{dt}=A(t)x$ are bounded in $[t_0, \infty)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

For real system of equations$$\frac{dx}{dt}=A(t)x,(1)$$ where $A(t) \in C[t_0, +\infty)$.

Prove that if $\int_{t_0}^{\infty} \|A(t_1)+A^T(t_1)\|< +\infty$ then all the roots of (1) are bounded in $[t_0, \infty)$.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: @ Parth Thakkar: $A(t)=((a_{ij}))_{n \times n}, a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$. Also, all roots it means every solution of (1).

Comment: $A^T$: It means the transpose of matrix $A$ is written $A^T$. Ok

Comment: Oh, that is the subject **Stability Theory** :) . You've ever heard it before?

Comment: Oh, anyway you're 17 years old. Perhaps, this is the first time you've heard it. I think **Amzoti** can help me, you are good at maths.

Comment: I'm sorry when I say that: I have a suggestion that if you know about the problem, then you can write down your ideas. If not it seem to like you're spammer! Thanks.

Comment: Who is 17 years old and how did this fact come to appear on this page?

Comment: @ **Did** : He deleted his comment. http://math.stackexchange.com/users/70311/parth-thakkar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How 'bout this:

Starting with the equation (1),

$\dot x = \frac{dx}{dt} = A(t)x \tag{1}$

we take the inner product of each side with $x$:

$\langle x,\dot x \rangle = \langle x, A(t)x \rangle, \tag{2}$

and then use the fact that

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle x, x \rangle = \langle \dot x, x \rangle +  \langle x,  \dot x \rangle = \langle x,\dot x \rangle +  \langle x,  \dot x \rangle = 2 \langle x,  \dot x \rangle \tag{3}$

to re-write (2) as

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle x, x \rangle = 2\langle x, A(t)x \rangle, \tag{4}$

and then go to work re-arranging (4):

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle x, x \rangle = 2\langle x, A(t)x \rangle = \langle A(t)x, x \rangle + \langle x, A(t)x \rangle$
$= \langle x,  A^T(t)x \rangle + \langle x, A(t)x \rangle = \langle x, (A^T(t) + A(t))x \rangle, \tag{5}$

and then keep on working at it:

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle x, x \rangle = \langle x, (A^T(t) + A(t))x \rangle$
$\le \Vert x \Vert \Vert (A^T(t) + A(t))x \Vert \le \Vert (A^T(t) + A(t)) \Vert \Vert x \Vert^2, \tag{6}$

and then finally use

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle x, x \rangle = \frac{d}{dt}\Vert x \Vert^2 \tag{7}$

to convert (6) to

$\frac{d}{dt}\Vert x \Vert^2 \le \Vert (A^T(t + A(t)) \Vert \Vert x \Vert^2, \tag{8}$

and then use the following fact, which follows from the uniqueness of the solutions of (1), which follows from the Lipschitz continuity of its right-hand side with respect to $x$, and its continuity with respect to $x$ and $t$, which I'll leave y'all to work out for yourselves, or else ask yet another question:  any $x(t)$ satisfying (1) is either *never* zero, or it is *always* zero, zero identically, since the only solution (by uniqueness!) with $x(t) = 0$ *somewhere* is the one with $x(t) = 0$ *everywhere*.  Well, the solution with $x(t) = 0$ everywhere looks pretty bounded to me!  So that means we can take $x(t) \ne 0$ everywhere, which means we can divide (8) through by $\Vert x \Vert^2$ to obtain

$\frac{d}{dt} \ln (\Vert x \Vert^2) \le  \Vert (A^T(t)+ A(t)) \Vert, \tag{9}$

which means that we can integrate (9) to obtain

$\ln (\Vert x(t) \Vert^2) - \ln (\Vert x(t_0) \Vert^2) \le \int_{t_0}^t \Vert (A^T(s)+ A(s)) \Vert ds, \tag{10}$

and then do even *more* re-arranging, this time of the logarithmo-algebraic sort, to get

$2\ln (\frac{\Vert x(t) \Vert}{\Vert x(t_0) \Vert}) \le \int_{t_0}^t \Vert (A^T(s)+ A(s)) \Vert ds, \tag{10}$

whence

$\Vert x(t) \Vert \le \Vert x(t_0) \Vert \exp(\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_0}^t \Vert (A^T(s)+ A(s)) \Vert ds), \tag{11}$

and since by hypothesis the integral occurring in the exponential on the right is bounded as $t \to \infty$, it follows that $x(t)$ is as well.  QED.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio, and as always

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @ **Robert Lewis** : Your answer is excellent, from your presentation to explain, that's very easy to understand for me. You have made my problems become simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer!

It seems that you are very busy, and don't have much time to ANSWER? 
(asked Sep 14 at 8:37 $\to$ answered  Sep 22)

**Here's my solution:**

- Since $\dot{x(t)}=A(t)x(t)\implies \mathrm{\dot{x}^T(t)=x^T(t)A^T(t)}$ $\implies \left\{\begin{matrix}
   & \mathrm{ x^T\dot{x}=x^TAx} \\ 
   & \mathrm{\dot{x}^Tx=x^TA^Tx}
  \end{matrix}\right.
  $

Thus $\dfrac{d}{dt} \mathrm{\left ( x^Tx \right)}=\mathrm{ x^T \dot{x}}+\mathrm{\dot{x}^Tx}=\mathrm{x^T(A+A^T)x} \implies \dfrac{d}{dt}\left ( \|x(t)\|^2 \right )=x^T(t)\left [ A(t)+A^T(t) \right ]x(t)$

- By integration on $\left [ t_0 , t \right ]$, one gets:$$\|x(t)\|^2 =\|x(t_0)\|^2 +\int_{t_0}^{t}x^T(s)\left [ A(s)+A^T(s) \right ]x(s)\mathrm{d}s$$
- Whence $$\|x(t)\|^2 \le \|x(t_0)\|^2 +\int_{t_0}^{t}\|x^T(s)\|\left  \|A(s)+A^T(s) \right \| \|x(s)\| \mathrm{d}s  $$  $$= \|x(t_0)\|^2 +\int_{t_0}^{t}\left  \|A(s)+A^T(s) \right \| \|x(s)\|^2\mathrm{d}s$$
- Applying **Gronwall - Bellman's inequality**, we have:
  $$\|x(t)\|^2 \le \|x(t_0)\|^2 \cdot\exp \int_{t_0}^{t}\left  \|A(s)+A^T(s) \right \| \mathrm{d}s  \\\\ \le \|x(t_0)\|^2 \cdot\exp \int_{t_0}^{+\infty}\left  \|A(s)+A^T(s) \right \| \mathrm{d}s< +\infty, \forall t \ge t_0 \blacksquare $$ **QED.**